# Integratig XML file into my Html Website

Tags: javascript, xml

I Want to integrate an xml file into my html-php website. The xml contents like follows.

```
  <url>
      <loc>http://www.qwer.com/</loc>
      <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
      <loc>http://www.qwerty.com/index.php</loc>
      <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    </url>
```

Iam using the following javascript to get elements from the xml file.

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","sitemap.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

document.write("<table border='1'>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
  document.write("<tr><td>");
  document.write("<a href='"+x[i].getElementsByTagName("loc")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"'>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("changefreq")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</a>");
  document.write("</td><td>");
  }
document.write("</table>");
```

But the value is not getting properly.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Use `Jquery`. The code will become much simpler.

Comment: "But the value is not getting properly" — What does this mean? What is it? What should it be? Do you get any errors?

Comment: No. Iam getting only the blank page. values are not fetching from the xml file

Comment: Can you see the HTTP request being made in the browser's developer tools' net tab? Can you add `console.log` statements to the JS to see which lines of code are being called and when?

Answer (score 1):

You must have a root tag in the XML.

And you have an error in your code.

```
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
```

should be

```
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("url");
```